# ImageView showing black/white background for transparent base64 string image

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

Im using [DisplayingBitmap.zip](http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/DisplayingBitmaps.zip) downloaded from developers android site to load images asynchronously into the imageview. Im receiving base64 strings from webservice. so modified the code to convert base64 to bitmap in ImageFetcher.class from (DisplayingBitmaps) instead of downloading image from url.

**NOTE:** Im receiving gif images in the form of base64 string.

**Converting base64 to Bitmap**

```
        public Bitmap convertBase64ToImage(String mBase64String) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                String imageDataBytes = mBase64String.substring(mBase64String.indexOf(",") + 1);
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

**Converting base64 bitmap to file inorder to obtain decoded resized bitmap using processBitmap method in ImageFetcher.class(DisplayingBitmaps):**

```
/**
         * The main process method, which will be called by the ImageWorker in the AsyncTask background
         * thread.
         *
         * @param data The data to load the bitmap, in this case, a regular http URL
         * @return The downloaded and resized bitmap
         */
        private Bitmap processBitmap(String data, String imageID) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                PrintLog.error(TAG, "processBitmap --- imageID " + imageID);
            } 
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            bitmap = convertBase64ToImage(data);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                File f = null;
                try {
                    //create a file to write bitmap data
                    f = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), imageID);
                    f.createNewFile();

                    //Convert bitmap to byte array
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100/*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                    //write the bytes in file
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fos.write(bitmapdata);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), mImageWidth, mImageHeight, getImageCache());
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data, String imageID) {
            return processBitmap(String.valueOf(data), imageID);
        }
```

**decodeSampledBitmapFromFile method from ImageResizer.class**

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filename, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, ImageCache cache) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, try to use inBitmap
        if (DeviceUtils.hasHoneycomb()) {
            addInBitmapOptions(options, cache);
        }

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename, options);
    }
```

**Implementing ImageFetcher.class(DisplayingBitmaps.zip) in my class**

```
    private static final String IMAGE_CACHE_DIR = "clubsCategoryIcons";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageCache.ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCache.ImageCacheParams(getActivity(), IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);
        cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.25f); // Set memory cache to 10% of app memory

        // The ImageFetcher takes care of loading images into our ImageView children asynchronously
        mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(getActivity(), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_icon_size));
        mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.settings_clubs);
        mImageFetcher.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), cacheParams);
    }
```

**passing this mImageFetcher object to adapter class to load images asynchronously for each item.**

```
ClubsCategoryAdapter clubsAdapter = new ClubsCategoryAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<ClubsCategoryParser.ClubsCategory>(), mImageFetcher);
recyclerView.setAdapter(clubsAdapter);
```

**ClubsCategoryAdapter.class**

```
public class ClubsCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

public ClubsCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ClubsCategoryParser.ClubsCategory> clubsCategoryList, ImageFetcher mImageFetcher ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.clubsCategoryList = clubsCategoryList;
        this.mImageFetcher = mImageFetcher;
}

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        final ClubsCategoryParser.ClubsCategory singleItem = clubsCategoryList.get(position);
        if (!TextUtils.isNullOrEmpty(singleItem.image_url)) {
                mImageFetcher.loadImage(singleItem.image_url, String.valueOf(singleItem.ID), viewHolder.imgCategoryIcon);
            }
```

**loadImage method in ImageWorker.class(DisplayingBitmaps)**

```
public void loadImage(Object data, String imageID, ImageView imageView) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }

        BitmapDrawable value = null;

        if (mImageCache != null) {
            value = mImageCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(imageID);
        }

        if (value != null) {
            // Bitmap found in memory cache
            imageView.setImageDrawable(value);
        } else if (cancelPotentialWork(data, imageView)) {
            //BEGIN_INCLUDE(execute_background_task)
            final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(data, imageID, imageView);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new AsyncDrawable(mResources, mLoadingBitmap, task);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
            // NOTE: This uses a custom version of AsyncTask that has been pulled from the
            // framework and slightly modified. Refer to the docs at the top of the class
            // for more info on what was changed.
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.DUAL_THREAD_EXECUTOR);
            //END_INCLUDE(execute_background_task)
        }
    }
```

**actual asynctask to process the image asynchronously**

```
 /**
     * The actual AsyncTask that will asynchronously process the image.
     */
    private class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, BitmapDrawable> {
        private Object mData;
        private String imageID;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public BitmapWorkerTask(Object data, String imageID, ImageView imageView) {
            mData = data;
            this.imageID = imageID;
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        /**
         * Background processing.
         */
        @Override
        protected BitmapDrawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //BEGIN_INCLUDE(load_bitmap_in_background)
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                PrintLog.error(TAG, "doInBackground - starting work");
            }

            final String dataString = String.valueOf(mData);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            BitmapDrawable drawable = null;

            // Wait here if work is paused and the task is not cancelled
            synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
                while (mPauseWork && !isCancelled()) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("pauseWork", "iswaiting -------------");
                        mPauseWorkLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.e("pauseWork", "iswaiting end -------------");
            // If the image cache is available and this task has not been cancelled by another
            // thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still bound back
            // to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set then try and fetch the bitmap from
            // the cache
            if (mImageCache != null && !isCancelled() && getAttachedImageView() != null && !mExitTasksEarly) {
                bitmap = mImageCache.getBitmapFromDiskCache(imageID);
            }

            // If the bitmap was not found in the cache and this task has not been cancelled by
            // another thread and the ImageView that was originally bound to this task is still
            // bound back to this task and our "exit early" flag is not set, then call the main
            // process method (as implemented by a subclass)
            if (bitmap == null && !isCancelled() && getAttachedImageView() != null && !mExitTasksEarly) {
                bitmap = processBitmap(mData, imageID);
            }

            // If the bitmap was processed and the image cache is available, then add the processed
            // bitmap to the cache for future use. Note we don't check if the task was cancelled
            // here, if it was, and the thread is still running, we may as well add the processed
            // bitmap to our cache as it might be used again in the future
            if (bitmap != null) {
                if (DeviceUtils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                    // Running on Honeycomb or newer, so wrap in a standard BitmapDrawable
                    drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
                } else {
                    // Running on Gingerbread or older, so wrap in a RecyclingBitmapDrawable
                    // which will recycle automagically
                    drawable = new RecyclingBitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
                }

                if (mImageCache != null) {
                    mImageCache.addBitmapToCache(imageID, drawable);
                }
            }

            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                PrintLog.error(TAG, "doInBackground - finished work");
            }

            return drawable;
            //END_INCLUDE(load_bitmap_in_background)
        }

        /**
         * Once the image is processed, associates it to the imageView
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(BitmapDrawable value) {
            //BEGIN_INCLUDE(complete_background_work)
            // if cancel was called on this task or the "exit early" flag is set then we're done
            if (isCancelled() || mExitTasksEarly) {
                value = null;
            }

            final ImageView imageView = getAttachedImageView();
            if (value != null && imageView != null) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    PrintLog.error(TAG, "onPostExecute - setting bitmap");
                }
                setImageDrawable(imageView, value);
            }
            //END_INCLUDE(complete_background_work)
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(BitmapDrawable value) {
            super.onCancelled(value);
            synchronized (mPauseWorkLock) {
                mPauseWorkLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the ImageView associated with this task as long as the ImageView's task still
         * points to this task as well. Returns null otherwise.
         */
        private ImageView getAttachedImageView() {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

            if (this == bitmapWorkerTask) {
                return imageView;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Images are showing fine for the first time when installing the app, But after killing the app and loads the same page shows the image with the black/white background.**

I have tried many examples and articles.. But nothing helped. I don't know why its coming with the black/white background after killing/exiting the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is showing the image fine for the first time and displaying black background after re-openning app because "DisplayingBitmap" app caches the images to the filesystem using JPEG format. As you know JPEG doesn't support transparent mode.

Please open **ImageCache** class and look at the **#68** line:

```
private static final CompressFormat DEFAULT_COMPRESS_FORMAT = CompressFormat.JPEG;
```

To avoid black background I changed this value to PNG format:

```
private static final CompressFormat DEFAULT_COMPRESS_FORMAT = CompressFormat.PNG;
```

**UPDATE**:

Also, you can set compressFormat to JPEG:

```
ImageCache.ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCache.ImageCacheParams(getActivity(), IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);
        cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.25f);
cacheParams.compressFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
```

it works for me and hope it helps you.